# format combine Multi LIKE in SQL Server

Tags: sql

This is format => SELECT * FROM 'name_table' WHERE 'name_column' LIKE '[A,H,J,_A, .... ]%'

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Answer (score 0):

You would generally solve that using a regular expression.  As a general solution, you need to use `OR`

```
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' OR
      name LIKE 'H%' OR
      name LIKE 'J%' OR
      name LIKE '_A%'
```

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
WHERE name LIKE '[AHJ]%' OR name LIKE '_A%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using substring like-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (SUBSTRING(column,1,1) IN ('A','H','J')) OR (SUBSTRING(column,2,1) IN ('A'))
```